# Search end of string for pattern then output all the strings

Tags: php

I wan't to search the string for words that ends with **"um"** then output all the words that match that pattern

I tried to use regex but I'm a beginner and I'm having a hard time understanding how this works

```
<?php
$lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

$pattern = preg_match("/um$/", $lorem)
foreach ($pattern as $patterns) {
  echo $patterns;
}
 ?>
```

**Output:**

ipsum

cillum

laborum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
$lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

preg_match_all("/\b\w*um\b/", $lorem, $pattern);

foreach ($pattern[0] as $patterns) {
    echo $patterns."\n";
}
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/mK45m6

Comment: There is no need to group `um`. The pattern can be `\b\w+um\b`